# Json ajax seems to return data twice

Tags: php, android, ajax, jquery-mobile, getjson

This code returns the data from the $.getJSON twice unless I activate the evnt.stopImmediatePropagation(); line, in which case no data is returned on my android mobile device:

```
$(document).on('click', '#LoginClick', function(evnt) {

//    evnt.stopImmediatePropagation();

// Find other players

// Send a call to the backend for players
var lilength = $('li').length;
if (lilength == 0) {
  $.getJSON('http://www.cjneeds.com/ECG/getPlayers.php', function(Users) {

    // For each Player, add them to the list
    $.each(Users, function(i,User) {

      // Add each Player to the list
      $('<li/>').text(User['userName']).appendTo("#playerList");
    });

    // Refresh the list
    $("#playerList").listview('refresh');
  });
}
});
```

This is the html:

```
<div id="LoginPage" data-role="page">

<div data-role="header"><h1>Login to ECG</h1>
  <a id="LoginClick" href="#LoginSubmit" title="Submit login details">Submit</a>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
  <form>
    <div>
      <label for="UserName">User name</label>
      <input id="UserName" title="Enter your User Name" tabindex="1" type="text" placeholder="User name" maxlength="10" autofocus>
    </div>
    .
    .
    .
  </form>
</div>

<div data-role="footer"><h1>Educational card games</h1>
  <a href="#" title="Retrieve your password">Lost PW</a>
</div>

</div>
```

```
<div id="LoginSubmit" data-role="page">

<div data-role="header"><h1>You're up against:</h1>
   <a href="#DisplayHand" title="See your cards and the upturned card">Play</a>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
  <ol id="playerList" data-role="listview">
    <!-- The <li> elements of Players go here. -->
  </ol>
</div>

<div data-role="footer"><h1>To see your cards click 'Play'</h1></div>

</div>
```

and the php on the server:

```
<?php
class User {
  public $userName;
  public $password;
  public $emailAddress;
  public $ageLast;
}

// Make a list for Users
$Users = array();

// Make new User 1
$Users[0] = new User;
$Users[0]->userName = 'John';
$Users[0]->password = 'John';
$Users[0]->emailAddress = 'john@email.com';
$Users[0]->ageLast = '9';

// Make new User 2
$Users[1] = new User;
$Users[1]->userName = 'Jane';
$Users[1]->password = 'Jane';
$Users[1]->emailAddress = 'jane@email.com';
$Users[1]->ageLast = '8';

// Make new User 3
$Users[2] = new User;
$Users[2]->userName = 'Sally';
$Users[2]->password = 'Sally';
$Users[2]->emailAddress = 'sally@email.com';
$Users[2]->ageLast = '9';

// Pass to client
echo json_encode($Users);
?>
```

and it returns this (when the evnt.stopImmediatePropagation(); line is remmed out):

1. John
2. Jane
3. Sally
4. John
5. Jane
6. Sally

which seems to indicate that either the $.getJSON or the $.each is somehow executing twice?

I tried to set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cneeds/YCnu2/#) but could not get the json part to work properly.

Comment: Are you wrapping code in `pagecreate`, `pageinit` or any other page event?

Comment: @Omar - my first line of code is $(document).on('pageinit', function(){

Comment: Do you have more than one page? If yes, `$(document).on("pageinit", "#pageID", function () { $("#btnId").on("click", function () { code }); });`. It's possible that the same button is getting multiple bindings.

Comment: @Omar Hi Omar. Your solution worked!! Please make it an answer so that I can upvote you.
    $(document).on("pageinit", "#LoginPage", function () { $("#LoginClick").on("click", function () {

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you're handling the `click` event on the `$(document)`. Handle it instead on the link itself, to avoid triggering twice: `$('#LoginClick').on('click', function() {...`.

Even then, I'd suggest stopping event propagation, since you're using the click event of a link, which has a different default behavior defined.

Comment: Sadly that didn't change anything :-(
As before, it works fine in the browser with the evnt.stopImmediatePropagation(); enabled but then I don't get any output on the android mobile.

Comment: try `evnt.stopPropagation()`

Comment: that also doesn't work. The mobile displays nothing and the PC displays the list twice. The PC works correctly with evnt.stopImmediatePropagation(); but the mobile doesn't get to display the player list page even with evnt.stopImmediatePropagation(); as the last command in the LoginClick function.
I will try some other mobile devices later to see if it's consistent on the mobile platform